# How to change Akka router size?

Tags: java, resize, akka, router

I have an Akka router like this:

```
ActorRef router = getContext().actorOf(
    new RoundRobinPool(instancecount)
        .props(Props.create(Node.class, po)), po.getUID());
```

then I want to change the router `instancecount`. What should I do?

Comment: Why would you want to change it after creation?

Comment: Because I want to modify the size of the router by using control page, and this in a production environment will be modified from time to time

Comment: But the most likely thing you will want to do, is matching the size of the router to the number of available cores. And this is very unlikely to change. And i don't think that this is easily possible. I guess you will have to to stop the old router and create a new one with your snippet above. But you could use a Message to do this :-)

Comment: You need to think about what types of situations would cause you to resize your router.  If you needed elasticity to handle occasional bursts of load, then just configure an appropriate `Resizer` to scale the pool up and down when need be.  If you need permanent changes to the settings then just change the config and round-robin reboot (assuming you have high availability in your infrastructure) your servers.  Don't invent code for something that is probably best handled with existing functionality/config from Akka.  Keep it simple.

Comment: Thank you for your help.How to use the Resizer? Can you give me a sample? I can't find the sample in Akka API.

Comment: Added as an answer...

Answer (score 4):

I think a `Resizer` could be something you could try to give you elasticity in your router pools to handle bursts of load.  If you wanted to programmatically setup a router with a resizer, then that would look something like this (taken from Akka example on [Routing](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/routing.html) 
 docs):

```
val resizer = DefaultResizer(lowerBound = 2, upperBound = 15)
val router3 = system.actorOf(Props[ExampleActor1].withRouter(
  RoundRobinRouter(resizer = Some(resizer))))
```

In this example, the pool will start out with 2 routees, but can scale up to 15 based on the volume of messages passing through the head of the router pool.  You could also do this straight from your akka config.  If you had config like this (again from Akka docs):

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  /myrouter2 {
    router = round-robin
    resizer {
      lower-bound = 2
      upper-bound = 15
    }
  }
}
```

Then you could setup your pool like this to take advantage of the config:

```
val router = system.actorOf(Props[ExampleActor].withRouter(FromConfig()), "myrouter2")
```

Check out the docs that I linked to for more info on how to setup a `Resizer` for your pools.  Hopefully this is a solution that meets your needs.

Comment: Thank you. you use the Resizer when creating the router pool in your example, but I want to change it after creation, and I don't know the upper-bound when I create the router pool, so is there other ways to change the size of the router pool? Or can we change the upper-bound of the Resizer when after creation?